# Null reference Error on AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.UserID

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, authentication

Using Unity editor currently to test FB Login.  Getting Null reference exception.  Will login once if I clear registry of all session details.

Have tried some hotfixes previously found with SDK updates.  This is an older sdk as the version of unity the game was written for was 5.3.3

```
private void initSession() {
    Debug.Log("FbManager init session");

    string logType = PlayerPrefs.GetString("LoggedType");
    if (logType.Equals("Facebook")) {
        GameManager.Instance.facebookIDMy = 
AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.UserId;
        callApiToGetName();
        getMyProfilePicture(GameManager.Instance.facebookIDMy);


        LoggedIn = true;
```

Expect login to persist and be retrieved based on token stored in registry

Comment: StackTrace is required.

Comment: Have you tried logging out before login?